# Where do the names of the Stack Overflow trilogy sites come from?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, superuser, serverfault

Why are the names of the Stack Overflow trilogy so named?

How did the names Stack Overflow, Server Fault and Super User come to be the ones used?

Comment: "Buffer Overflow" is surely what you were thinking of RE: hacking and security?

Answer (score 27):

On the names of the sites of [the original trilogy](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/the-stack-overflow-trilogy/):

#### Stack Overflow

> #### [Help Name Our Website](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/04/help-name-our-website.html)
>
> We've racked our collective brains, and this is the best we could do. We'd like your input to see if we're on the right track. Vote for the name that best embodies what you'd like to see on a software developer community website.
>
> - stackoverflow.com
> - privatevoid.com
> - dereferenced.com
> - humbledeveloper.com
> - bitoriented.com
> - fellowhackers.com

#### Server Fault

> #### [IT Stack Overflow Update: Naming is Hard](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/03/it-stack-overflow-update-naming-is-hard/)
>
> At the moment I am leaning heavily toward the name serverfault.com. A quick straw poll on Twitter got reasonably positive results. I realize it’s not as good a name as Stack Overflow.

#### Super User

> seriously considering paying $10k for what I think is a pretty killer domain name. Is this a bad idea? Am I crazy? [somebody hold me!](http://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/1965603283)

Comment: Scary - a few votes the other way and we may have wound up  privatevoid.com

Comment: @AdamRackis Which would make the network Private(s)Exchange? Scary, indeed.

Comment: @Anna - Jeff'd have to add a hyphen!  Privates-Exchange

Comment: I would have preferred segfault.com.

Answer (score 16):

It's a kind of exception you might experience in software (using infinite recursion, for example).

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow)

> In software, a stack overflow occurs when too much memory is used on the call stack. The call stack contains a limited amount of memory, often determined at the start of the program. The size of the call stack depends on many factors, including the programming language, machine architecture, multi-threading, and amount of available memory. When too much memory is used on the call stack the stack is said to overflow, typically resulting in a program crash.

You might also be interested in [this discussion](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/04/help-name-our-website.html), which is where the name came from.

Comment: And to think... the site was almost called "PrivateVoid". <shudders>