# Why Stack Overflow's name for that site?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where does the name “Stack Overflow” come from?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61541/where-does-the-name-stack-overflow-come-from)

Why Stack Overflow's name for that site?

Comment: You should ask questions about the site here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Well, reading the subject, then the body, then the subject, then the body, etcetera to find the real question produces the problem that the site is named for.

Answer (score 4):

The name was chosen in a poll on Jeff Atwood's blog "Coding Horror":

- http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/04/help-name-our-website.html

Comment: I wonder what would have happened if `metaprogramming.com` had won. Would there be `meta.metaprogramming.com`?

Comment: hahahaha, stack overflow has been a tremendous success...