# Why is Stack Overflow named as Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where does the name “Stack Overflow” come from?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61541/where-does-the-name-stack-overflow-come-from)

Why not Stack Underflow or something else :) ?

Comment: http://jcooney.net/post/2010/08/26/Back-in-the-day-preferred-the-name-gosub10com-over-stackoverflowcom.aspx

Comment: Duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61541/where-does-the-name-stack-overflow-come-from, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69467/why-stack-overflows-name-for-that-site

Comment: @silky I never understood why expert wanted a gender change. And why they needed a pay model.

Answer (score 1):

This recursive question just threw a StackOverflow exception in my head, since you would ask this on whatever other name it would have been ;)

Comment: thats convincing. But that implies, every other blog/forum should also be named like that :) ??? or in other words, every other site should be 'stackoverflow' ?

Comment: Now the SO became doomed...