# Origin of Names of StackExchange Sites (Trilogy)

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where do the names of the Stack Overflow trilogy sites come from?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61541/where-do-the-names-of-the-stack-overflow-trilogy-sites-come-from)

Were the names of the original StackExchange sites purposely chosen to be compound-words starting with ‘s’ (SE, SO, SF, SU) or is it just a coincidence?

Comment: IT was definitely not a coincidence.  There was a naming contest for the second sites.

Comment: Server fault naming contest: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/coming-in-march-it-stack-overflow/

Comment: Actually, SuperUser was an existing domain that Jeff instantly liked and purchased.  (Looking for reference)

Comment: Here we go: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/the-stack-overflow-trilogy/ - `I was thrilled to be able to secure the domain name superuser.com from fellow geek (and dual-class photographer / sysadmin) Noah Beil. As I’ve mentioned before, naming is hard, and it’s so rare to find a name that a) I like, and b) is available.`

Comment: And finally, SO's naming contest from Coding Horror - http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/04/help-name-our-website.html (Thanks @random)

Comment: *Re “exact duplicate”:* Why does the search function not function well?