# How does Stack Overflow generate revenue?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, revenue

Stack Overflow generates revenue, how?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would imagine that most of the revenue comes from advertising. There are adverts displayed on most pages and some tags are also sponsored.

Comment: OK. I'm kinda new here, but I haven't seen a single advert yet.

Comment: That's actually what set me off looking for this question, @Jeff -- I didn't see any adverts either, and I was curious how they ran the servers without making money.

Comment: There is no advertising at SO.

Answer (score 3):

Some revenue comes from referral sales (sorry, don't know the exact term). Some book titles are converted to amazon links (not sure manually or automagically, though I would assume the latter). Example page is here: [What is the single most influential book every programmer should read?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711/what-is-the-single-most-influential-book-every-programmer-should-read)