# Personal Message to Users

Tags: discussion, private-messaging

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Any way to send a personal message to another user?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/any-way-to-send-a-personal-message-to-another-user)

Is there any facility to send personal message to users of stackoverflow??

Comment: [At least one question of yours](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64219/how-stackoverflow-generates-revenue) has been moved to http://meta.stackoverflow.com. Please visit that site to ask questions about this site.

Comment: I am sure this has already been discussed many times before on meta.stackoverflow.com.

Comment: Post a comment on any of his answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only via mechanisms that the user has exposed in their profile or via mutual participation in [chat](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/).  The SO framework explicitly does not include a mechanism to send a direct message (at least, so far).