# What's going on with "Potential Stack Overflow Revenue Models"?

Tags: discussion, meta, undelete-request

There is a [deleted question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24421/potential-stackoverflow-revenue-models/) that has been linked to by [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64219/how-does-stack-overflow-generate-revenue), and from the title, it seems to be of historical significance. However, I don't have 10k, so I will need someone else to read it for me and either undelete it and protect it, or explain why it was deleted. Anyone?

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79435/what-is-stack-overflows-business-model

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> deleted by Jeff Atwood♦ Feb 1 '12 at 8:52

No idea *why*, exactly, but I'm not inclined to undelete a 4-year-old question that was about the community coming up with revenue ideas. A lot of stuff happened in four years, and in any case, I think we'd rather discuss specific suggestions or ideas instead of building a list of them for its own sake.

But, for completeness' sake, here's the answer that was linked to in the other post you mentioned. From our very own [Shog9](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/811/shog9):

> SO-branded, WiFi-soaked Waffle Houses!

(I don't know about you, but I could go for a waffle right about now.)

Comment: I like the blueberry kind myself.  I should get some.

Comment: I should go get a waffle right now. I'll name it Sam as a tribute.

Comment: A *stack* of waffles *overflowing* with maple syrup?