# Why the name as StackOverflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why was Stack Overflow named Stack Overflow? Where does its money come from?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3857/why-was-stack-overflow-named-stack-overflow-where-does-its-money-come-from)

I always wonder why this site has name **StackOverflow**? Whats in the stack and how it is over flowing?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow . The second part of the question belongs more to the main site, not to meta :)

Comment: whats the relation between above link and this site? I know the meaning of stack overflow, but why it is used as name to this site?

Comment: As dupe says - the [first democratic action](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/04/help-name-our-website.html) (as far as I know) :)

Comment: It was chosen by voters: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/04/help-name-our-website.html

Comment: Still disappointed it wasn't named FellowWhackers.com

Comment: Perhaps when we get Emergency Medical Technicians SE through A51, @TheEstablishment. (@sixlettervariables too even though I know that won't work.)